# unable to import file to the project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, import

[image]

Hi guys, I'm trying to import model.json file as you can see in the VS its right there! why is it still failing to import it? am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like assets folder is on the same level as components. So in order to go to the assets folder, you will have to go up one level from the components folder and then enter the assets folder:
`../assets/model/model.json`

Answer (score 1):

Its not in the `components` folder, you should try:

```
require('../assets/model/model.json')
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your "FaceApp.tsx" is inside "components" directory and the JSON your trying to load is in "assets" directory which is **not** inside the "components" directory.

When you use the "./" prefix you basically saying that you want to load the file from the current directory.
thus, using "./assets/model/model.json" will evaluate as "components/assets/model/model.json".

Try using "../assets/model/model.json" instead.

Hope this helps, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing cache using `yarn start --reset-cache`
Ref: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1924